# How to get position (latitude and longitude) from a postal (zip) code in react?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, latitude-longitude, google-geolocation

I need to know what is the best way to get latitude and longitude from a postal (zip) code in react ?

I try with geocode from google API (with the npm package react-geocode), but I can't do a search based on only the postal code.

So I need your opinion on how to do that. Example of sources code will be also appreciate.

Thank you in advance for all your comments. Regards...

Comment: Why do you assume this is possible at all? Postal code, AFAIK, corresponds not to a pair of coordinates, but to entire area, sometimes disjoint.

Comment: 1. Constrain the problem: postal code systems vary wildly around the world (format, granularity etc). Are you after any particular country? 2. Recommendations for libraries are out of topic on SO, recommendations for geolocation databases even more so - I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @Cerberus : it's not wrong, but then how could I do ? I want the user enter their zip code and then I would like to get an approximately a geographic coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this and adjust it to your needs as only few context is given:

```
 var lat = '';
 var lng = '';

// depends on whether you really only have the zip code
 var address = {zipcode} or {city and state};

 geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
     });
   } else {
     console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
   }
 });
 console.log('Latitude: ' + lat + ' Longitude: ' + lng);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // using react-geocode package I was able to successfully capture lat lng of Pincode.  
      GeoCode.setApiKey("YOUR API KEY");
        GeoCode.setLanguage("en");
        GeoCode.setRegion("in");
    
        const getGeoCode = (e) => {
        let zipCode = e.target.value;
        const latitude = ''
    
        GeoCode.fromAddress(zipCode).then(({ results }) => {
          const { lat, lng } = results[0].geometry.location;
          createTicketFormik.values.lat = lat;
          createTicketFormik.values.lng = lng;
        });
        };
       <TextField
       fullWidth
       type="number"
       size="small"
       name="postalCode"
       InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: 14 } }}
       label="Postal Code"             
       onInput={getGeoCode}
       />
```